# Java URL Encoding additional characters

Tags: java

I'm having some troubles getting an HTTP Get call to work.

I concatenate the string and print it before opening the connection.

So my string is as the following:

http://example.com?Adri%E1n%20

However, the server is receiving it as:

http://example.com?Adri%EF%BF%BDn%20

I don't know if the problem is on the server side, or when making the call from Java.

Please help.

Additional info: (%E1 = á)

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue outright.  Are you encoding things using ASCII or UTF-8?

Comment: I'm currently using UTF-8, I have also tried manually encoding using replace.()....

Comment: Can you show how you send the request? some codes?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("á", "UTF-8"));
```

prints

%C3%A1